# Why svn2git causes loop to break in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, svn2git

I am trying to migrate some modules from SVN to GIT using svn2git. I have a list of modules in .csv file like this:

```
pl.com.neokartgis.i18n;pl.com.neokartgis.i18n;test-gis;svniop
pl.com.neokartgis.cfg;pl.com.neokartgis.cfg;test-gis;svniop
pl.com.neokart.db;pl.com.neokart.db;test-gis;svniop
```

I want to migrate each module to separate GIT repository. I tried following script that reads list of modules from .csv file and import each module in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=$1
SVN_PATH=svn://svn.server/path/to/root
DIR=`pwd`

function importToGitModule {
    cd $DIR

    rm -rf /bigtmp/svn2git/repo
    mkdir /bigtmp/svn2git/repo
    cd /bigtmp/svn2git/repo
    svn2git --verbose $SVN_PATH/$1  
    #some other stuff with imported repository
}

cat $LIST | gawk -F";" '{ print $2; }' | while read module_to_import
do
    echo "before import $module_to_import"
    importToGitModule "$module_to_import";
done;
```

The problem is that the script ends after first iteration. However if I remove call to `svn2git`, script works as expected and prints message for each module in file.

My question is: why this script ends after first iteration and how can I change it to import all modules in a loop?

**EDIT:**

Following version of loop works correctly:

```
for module_to_import in `cat $LIST | gawk -F";" '{ print $2; }'`
do
    echo "before import $module_to_import"
    importToGitModule "$module_to_import";
done;
```

So why `while read` doesn't work?

Comment: Try running `svn2git` in a subshell: `(svn2git --verbose "$SVN_PATH/$1")`

Comment: Unfortunately that dosen't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that something inside your loop -- possibly part of the `svn2git` process -- is consuming `stdin`.  Consider a loop like this:

```
ls /etc | while read file; do
    echo "filename: $file"
    cat > /tmp/data
done
```

Regardless of how many files are in `/etc`, this loop will only run once.  The `cat` in this loop will consume all the other input on `stdin`.

You can see if you have encountered the same situation by explicitly redirecting `stdin` from `/dev/null`, like this:

```
cat $LIST | gawk -F";" '{ print $2; }' | while read module_to_import
do
    echo "before import $module_to_import"
    importToGitModule "$module_to_import" < /dev/null
done
```